# Why query has ambiguous symbols?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I use sqlite3 in my c++ app, and also I use as SQLiteStudio to debug my queries.

I have two almost equivalent database `DB` and `DB1`. Both have same table `Tab1` with (almost) same fields: DB.Tab1 = [`a, b, c, d`] columns and DB1.Tab1 = [`a, b, c, d, e`] columns.

When I try to execute this query:

`SELECT DB1.Tab1.a, DB1.Tab1.b, DB1.Tab1.c FROM DB1.Tab1 LEFT JOIN Tab1 ON (DB1.Tab1.a = Tab1.a);`

I have some strange error: `ambiguous name: Tab1.a`.

*Before this query I have opened `DB` and then attached `DB1` to my current connection.*

I have tried join two tables on another field `d`, tried to select more or less fields, tried to specify full or short names - it always the same error `ambiguous name` even if it is only one place where I use this column.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: use synonym of one tablename in other connection to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tables are the same name, but in different databases.  That confuses me, much less a SQL compiler.

Just assign your own aliases:

```
SELECT dt1.a, dt1.b, dt1.c
FROM DB1.Tab1 dt1 LEFT JOIN
     Tab1 t1
     ON dt1.a = t1.a;
```

The problem is that `tab1.a` could refer to either `tab1.a` or `db1.tab1.a`, based on the rules that SQL uses for aliases.

Comment: I didn't know that, Thanks!